# Obtaining both Solutions of Linear, Second-Order ODE using DSolve

Tags: differential-equations, bugs, symbolic, special-functions

**Bug introduced in 10.4 or earlier and persisting through 11.3**

**Reported as CASE:3849226.**

While attempting to provide a general answer for [question 138321](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/138321/1063), I obtained a result,

```
Flatten@DSolve[{D[(1 - R/r) D[Φ[r], r], r] - ((n (n + 1))/r^2) Φ[r] == 0}, Φ[r], r, 
    Assumptions -> n ∈ Integers && n > 0]
{* {Φ[r] -> (r^2 C[1] Hypergeometric2F1[1 - n, 2 + n, 3, r/R])/R^2 + 
             C[2] MeijerG[{{}, {1 - n, 2 + n}}, {{0, 2}, {}}, r/R]} *)
```

which appears to be incorrect.  For instance, plot the two ostensibly independent solutions for `n == 2` (and `x == r/R`).

```
Plot[Evaluate[{x^2 Hypergeometric2F1[1 - n, 2 + n, 3, x],
    -MeijerG[{{}, {1 - n, 2 + n}}, {{0, 2}, {}}, x]/3} /. n -> 2], {x, 0, 1.2}, 
    PlotRange -> All, Exclusions -> None]
```

[image]

Two problems are evident.  First, the two solutions are identical (up to a constant multiplier, here `1/3`) for `x < 1`.  Second, neither solution is singular at `x == 1`, even though it is not difficult to show that one solution should have a logarithmic singularity there.  Incidentally,

```
FunctionExpand[MeijerG[{{}, {1 - n, 2 + n}}, {{0, 2}, {}}, r/R], Abs[r/R] < 1]
(* Hypergeometric2F1[-1 - n, n, 1, 1 - r/R] *)
```

which I am confident is proportional to `r^2 Hypergeometric2F1[1 - n, 2 + n, 3, r/R])/R^2` for all positive integer `n`.  although I have not searched the myriad Hypergeometric Function identities to prove it.

So, my questions are

1. Is this a bug?
2. Is there a `DSolve` work-around to obtain the second independent solution of the ODE?

**Addendum: Correct n == 2 solution**

Further insight can be gained by solving the ODE for a specific value of `n`, which `DSolve` can handle correctly.  For instance, with `n == 2`,

```
s2 = With[{n = 2}, FullSimplify@Flatten@DSolveValue[{D[(1 - R/r) D[Φ[r], r], r] -
    ((l (l + 1))/r^2) Φ[r] == 0}, Φ[r], r]]
 (* (3 r^2 (4 r - 3 R) R^5 C[1] - 8 R (-24 r^2 + 6 r R + R^2) C[2] + 
    48 r^2 (4 r - 3 R) C[2] (-Log[r] + Log[r - R]))/(12 R^5) *)
```

The `C` are arbitrary constants.  For convenience in plotting, set them to `C[1] -> - R^-3` and `C[2] -> - R^2/(16 Pi)`.

```
s2s = FullSimplify[{-Coefficient[s2, C[1]]/R^3, -ReIm@Coefficient[s2, C[2]] R^2/(16 Pi)} 
    /. r -> x R, R > 0 && x > 0]
(* {((3 - 4*x)*x^2)/4, {(1 + 6*(1 - 4*x)*x + 6*(3 - 4*x)*x^2*Re[Log[(-1 + x)/x]])/(24*Pi), 
    Piecewise[{{((3 - 4*x)*x^2)/4, x < 1}}, 0]}} *)

Plot[Evaluate[s2s], {x, 0, 1.2}, PlotRange -> {-.4, .4}, Exclusions -> None]
```

Comparing this plot with the first plot in the question makes clear that the `DSolve` solution for arbitrary positive integer `n` is incomplete.  (The first solution is blue, `Re` of the second solution orange, and `Im` of the second solution green.)  Note that the green curve is not independent of the blue curve and could be eliminated by taking a linear combination of the first and second solutions for `0 < x < 1`.

[image]

Comment: I only got to look at this now. It seems to me that `DSolve[]` completely ignored your `n ∈ Integers`, since the two solutions are indeed independent for noninteger `n`, but collapse into a single one otherwise (reminiscent of the situation when solving Bessel's equation, where you need a special limiting operation to get $Y$ in addition to $J$).

Comment: To add: it might be profitable to try to bring the DE you have to hypergeometric form, based on the form of the solution you have, so that the solutions pairs featured [here](http://functions.wolfram.com/HypergeometricFunctions/Hypergeometric2F1/13/01/01/ShowAll.html) might be applicable.

Answer (score 1):

```
eqn = D[(1 - R/r) D[Φ[r], r], 
     r] - ((n (n + 1))/r^2) Φ[r] == 0;

assume = n ∈ Integers && n > 0;

sol = Assuming[assume, DSolve[eqn, Φ, r][[1]]]

(*  {Φ -> Function[{r}, 
       (r^2*C[1]*Hypergeometric2F1[
                1 - n, 2 + n, 3, r/R])/
           R^2 + C[2]*MeijerG[
             {{}, {1 - n, 2 + n}}, 
             {{0, 2}, {}}, r/R]]}  *)
```

The solution is valid for `Abs[r/R] < 1`

```
(eqn /. sol) // FullSimplify[#, assume && Abs[r/R] < 1] &

(*  True  *)
```

Or for `Abs[r/R] > 1`

```
(eqn /. sol) // FullSimplify[#, assume && Abs[r/R] > 1] &

(*  True  *)
```

However, the general solution fails for `Abs[r/R] == 1`

```
(eqn /. sol) // FullSimplify[#, assume && Abs[r/R] == 1] &

(*  Indeterminate == 0  *)
```

**EDIT:** The components are separately solutions

```
(eqn /. (sol /. C[1] -> 0)) // FullSimplify[#, assume && Abs[r/R] < 1] &

(*  True  *)

(eqn /. (sol /. C[2] -> 0)) // FullSimplify[#, assume && Abs[r/R] < 1] &

(*  True  *)

(eqn /. (sol /. C[1] -> 0)) // FullSimplify[#, assume && Abs[r/R] > 1] &

(*  True  *)

(eqn /. (sol /. C[2] -> 0)) // FullSimplify[#, assume && Abs[r/R] > 1] &

(*  True  *)
```

The discontinuity comes from the second component when `Abs[r/R] == 1`

```
(eqn /. (sol /. C[1] -> 0)) // FullSimplify[#, assume && Abs[r/R] == 1] &

(*  Indeterminate == 0  *)
```

The first component remains valid for `Abs[r/R] == 1`

```
(eqn /. (sol /. C[2] -> 0)) // FullSimplify[#, assume && Abs[r/R] == 1] &

(*  True  *)
```

Plotting the two independent solutions

```
Manipulate[
 Plot[Evaluate[
   List @@ (Φ[r] /. sol1) /.
    {C[1] -> c1, C[2] -> c2, 
     r -> x*R, n -> m}],
  {x, -1.1, 1.1},
  Exclusions -> {-1, 1},
  PlotRange -> All,
  AxesLabel -> {Style[ToString[x == r/R, TraditionalForm], 14, Bold], 
    None},
  PlotLegends -> Placed["Expressions", Above]],
 {{c1, 1}, -5, 5, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 {{c2, 1}, -5, 5, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 {{m, 2, "n"}, Range[5]}]
```

[image]

Comment: This answer does not show that the two solutions are independent for `Abs[x] < 1`, and they are not, as I noted in my question.  Neither is `0` an independent solution for `Abs[x] > 1`.

Comment: @bbgodfrey - setting either `C[1]` or `C[2]` to zero will separate the solutions and remain valid solutions.

Comment: Please see the addendum to my question.  The two solutions in your plot are not independent.