# How do I enforce this boundary condition?

Tags: differential-equations, boundary-condition-at-infinity

I am solving this differential equation:

```
(1 - 2 M/r) D[(1 - (2 M)/r) D[q[r], r], r] - (1 - 2 M/r) ((l (l + 1))/r^2 - (6 M)/r^3) q[r]
```

with the boundary conditions that `q[0]==0` and $q\rightarrow\dfrac{1}{r^l}$ at infinity. How do I enforce the second condition?

Comment: Do you need a symbolic solution or numeric solution? If the latter, what's the value of those paremeters?

Comment: @xzczd I need a numerical solution. You can set M=1 and l=2

Comment: If $l=2$, isn't the b.c. at infinity equivalent to $q(\infty)=0$?

Comment: @xzczd I am following this paper http://articles.adsabs.harvard.edu/pdf/1978ApJ...224..643C (page 4 of 25) They say to impose that b.c.

Comment: The output of `AsymptoticDSolveValue[{(1 - (2 M)/r) D[(1 - (2*M)/r)*D[q[r], r], 
      r] - (1 - (2 M)/r) ((l (l + 1))/r^2 - (6 M)/r^3) q[r] == 0(*,q[0]\[Equal]0*)}, 
 q@r, {r, Infinity, 1}]` seems to suggest such solution doesn't exist… Perhaps there's some deeper math here? Or the paper is wrong?

Comment: I am concerned about integrating through `r = 2 M`, where the ODE is singular.  The nonsingular solution there is `(1 - ((3 - l - l^2) (-2 M + r))/(2 M)) C[1]`, which translates into the boundary condition, `(-(((-3 + l + l^2) q[2 M])/(8 M^3)) + q'[2 M]/(4 M^2)) == 0`.  Combining this with `q[0] == 0` yields as the only solution `q[r] = 0`.  Integrating through event horizons is difficult.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mathematica's result doesn't really make sense with the paper you reference.  We can solve the ode without boundary conditions.

```
ode = (1 - (2*M)/r)*D[(1 - (2*M)/r)*D[q[r], r], r] - 
(1 - (2*M)/r)*((l*(l + 1))/r^2 - (6*M)/r^3)*q[r] == 0

$Assumptions = r >= 0 && M > 0

sol = DSolve[ode, q[r], r] // Flatten // FunctionExpand
```

We get hypergeometric functions, but they simplify if we define $l$.

For $l=2$

```
sol /. l -> 2 // Simplify
```

$\left\{q(r)\to c_2 \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 \{ & 
\begin{array}{cc}
 \frac{r^3}{8 M^3} & r<2 M \\
 0 & r>2 M \\
 \text{Indeterminate} & \text{True} \\
\end{array}
 \\
\end{array}
\right)-\frac{c_1 r^3}{8 M^3}\right\}$

We can make $q=0$ for $r<2M$ by setting $c_1=c_2$, but for $r>2M$ we get a solution proportional to $r^3$ which will not satisfy your boundary at infinity.

Comment: `DSolveValue[ode /. l -> 2, q[r], r]` gives a different answer, `r^3 C[1] + (C[2] (12 M^4 + 8 M^3 r + 6 M^2 r^2 + 6 M r^3 - 3 r^4 Log[r] + 3 r^4 Log[-2 M + r]))/(96 M^5 r)`.  The discrepancy is due to a bug in Mathematica that I reported to Wolfram Inc over three years ago.  See [138440](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/138440/1063).  Simply stated, Mathematica has given you only one independent solution instead of two due to this bug.  I agree, though, that this problem has no solution for the boundary conditions specified.